# Bash command with file descriptors

Tags: bash

I'm wondering what this command does:

```
/bin/sh -i <&3 >&3 2>&3
```

I know "-i" is to make a persistent command, and the rest is about files descriptors, but I'm confused here..

More precisely, I don't understand <&3, and why it's followed by >&3 and then 2>&3

Thanks

Comment: @JamesBrown Yes, but what about <&3 ?

Comment: @JamesBrown You're mistaken-- 1 is stdout and 2 is stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like something you would see with a `reverse shell` (e.g. when doing penetration testing). You would bind the file descriptor (3) to a TCP port to send data and read the responses.

So `/bin/sh -i <&3` would translate to:

"Read data from the TCP port and send to shell as input"

`>&3 2>&3` would translate to:

"Send stdout (fd 1) and stderr (fd2) output to file descriptor 3 so the remote shell can see what's being send to output".

Comment: Importantly, the `-i` ensures the shell is an interactive shell if file descriptor 3 is not a terminal.